# How to listen login fail / success with oauth2 grant_type=password

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-oauth2

My app uses spring cloud oauth2 rest and angular .

My goal is to use the spring server to limit the maximum number of login failures

angular2 login  code:

```
const body = "username=" + encodeURI(username) + "&password=" + encodeURI(password) +
      "&grant_type=password&client_id=" + encodeURI(this.clientId);

this.http.post("/oauth/token",body,{headers:authHeaders}).map{
...
}
```

spring auth-server web security code:

```
    @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.httpBasic().and().sessionManagement()
              .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
              .and().authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
      }
```

**I try these two event  :**

```
public class AuthenticationFailureListener
    implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent>{
@Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent e) {
  //...
}
}
```

and:

```
public class AuthenticationSuccessListener
    implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {
  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent e) {
//...
}
}
```

> But it not works

**How to listen "login fail and success  " ?**

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security will **NOT** publish **AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent** (login failed) event by **default**.

You need to **override** DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher with ApplicationEventPublisher.

This has to be done in your Authentication **Configuration** class as below.

```
@Configuration
protected static class MyAuthenticationConfiguration extends
        GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${ldap.url}")
    String url;

    @Value("${ldap.base}")
    String base;

    @Value("${ldap.managerDn}")
    String managerDn;

    @Value("${ldap.password}")
    String password;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;


    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication().userSearchFilter("sAMAccountName={0}")
                .userSearchBase(base).contextSource().url(url)
                .managerDn(managerDn).managerPassword(password);
        //This publisher will trigger AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent (AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent)
        auth.authenticationEventPublisher(new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher));

    }
```

**To support form based authentication**, add below into your configure() method.

```
.and().formLogin();
```

Entire configure method should be similar to below.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin();
super.configure(http);

}
```

Comment: LDAP Authentication is just example of authentication manager. You can use in-memory or jdbc authentication.